# Can i change the site url name of a site collection? - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a sharepoint online url e.g https://nnn.sharepoint.com/teams/Project
 But i would like to change it to MYProject.
Is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: Virendra, you can only change the URL of subsites. The Web Site Address option does not exist in the site settings for the site collection root site.

Answer (score 3):

No, You can't!

**For the ShrePoint Online** - You can't rename Site URL as per these links [link1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Can-t-rename-a-SharePoint-team-site-576325AD-8C40-4FE8-8A63-68C3B7D536CF?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) [link2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55264/change-urls-address-of-sharepoint-online#answers)

**SharePoint On-Premises** You can **change the Site Collection URL** with PowerShell Script.

Please check teh stpes given in the [link](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/07/how-to-change-site-collection-url.html), Also here is another [link](http://www.sharepointrelated.com/2015/03/30/change-site-collection-url-sharepoint/).

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 3):

As most of these answers point out, no, you cannot do this in SharePoint Online. There is a UserVoice topic on this as Gautum mentioned.

What everyone has failed to mention though, it can be achieved with migration tools. If you've invested in a tool like Metalogix, Sharegate, or Avepoint, you can copy the entire site collection into a new site collection with the desired url then delete the old one.

I highly recommend having one in your toolbox, they are invaluable for some of the reporting features and migration capabilities, both internally to SPO and SPO to SPO.

Comment: Still can't do this? I tried to use Sharegate as Eric suggests above, however, it doesn't 'see' hub communication tempate sites (I don't see them unless I go to the new admin view either). So that didn't help me much for what we're trying to rename since the source and destinations are not visible to the tool. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: As per the [Microsoft 365 Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoft-365/roadmap?rtc=1&searchterms=56205&filters=&searchterms=56205), this is being rolled out for SharePoint Online. It will automatically update all existing URLs and redirect the old URLs to the new pages. The UserVoice post has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to change `https://nnn.sharepoint.com/teams/Project` to `https://nnn.sharepoint.com/teams/MyProject`

Changing site collection url is not possible in SPO atleast not right now.

Reference- [Enable renaming the site collection URLs](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273492-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/7571643-enable-renaming-of-your-internal-sharepoint-url)

Upvote on the user voice.

Answer (score 1):

Site Collections URL cannot be renamed.
Only subsites can be renamed.
As a workaround you can explore Host named site collection facility in SharePoint 2013.

Comment: host name site collections are not applicable here as this is SPO

Comment: If i can change subsite.How can i change the url of a subsite ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From May 2019 onwards, we can rename the SharePoint site URLs from the central admin and PowerShell

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/SharePoint-Online-Can-Now-Rename-Site-URLs/m-p/512293